# How can I update to Android 4.4 manually?

Tags: updates, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-10.1

I have Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1' with Android version 4.1.2. Is it possible to manually to update to Android 4.4, and if yes how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not currently possible for non Nexus devices. For this you will have to wait until Samsung release a version of Android KitKat for your device or until a developer release a ROM based on Android 4.4 for your tablet ([CyanogenMod](http://www.cyanogenmod.org) for example).